# Issue accessing Custom Setting when instantiating Batch Class

Tags: apex, soql, batch, customsetting

I'm having issues returning values in a Custom setting (Type = List) when I'm instantiating a batch class, and I'm not sure why.

I'm doing an upsert in my test class and confirming via system debug that the values are inserted.

```
        //Create Custom Setting
        RoundRobinAssignments__c RoundRobin = new RoundRobinAssignments__c(
            Name = 'Master', OpportunityNonPackageLeads__c = 5, 
            OpportunityPackageLead__c =10);
        upsert RoundRobin;  
        
        List <RoundRobinAssignments__c> thresholdTEST = [SELECT id,OpportunityPackageLead__c,
                      OpportunityNonPackageLeads__c  
                   FROM RoundRobinAssignments__c];
        System.debug('thresholdTEST: '+ thresholdTEST);
```

In my batch class, I've written the below (I've tried the select statement that has been commented out too)

```
        //List <RoundRobinAssignments__c> threshold = [SELECT id,OpportunityPackageLead__c,OpportunityNonPackageLeads__c  FROM RoundRobinAssignments__c];
        RoundRobinAssignments__c threshold = RoundRobinAssignments__c.getValues('Master');
        System.debug('threshold: '+ threshold);
```

Debug Log:
[image: Debug Log]

Thoughts?

---

update from comments:

```
Result: 23:08:14:286 USER_DEBUG [81]|DEBUG|allData: {}
```

Calling Batch Class:

```
//execute the batch 
Test.startTest(); 
Database.executeBatch(new BatchOpportunityOwnerAssignment()); 
Test.stopTest();
```

Comment: what type is this custom setting? (Hierarchy or List)

Comment: Type = List, Visibility = Public

Comment: Can you try outputting all data and see if the map is empty? `Map<String, RoundRobinAssignments__c> allData = RoundRobinAssignments__c.getAll(); system.debug('allData: ' + allData);` and can you post more of the unit test class to show how the batch class is being called?

Comment: @MarkPond Result: 23:08:14:286 USER_DEBUG [81]|DEBUG|allData: {}

Calling Batch Class:
//execute the batch
        Test.startTest(); 
        Database.executeBatch(new BatchOpportunityOwnerAssignment());
        Test.stopTest();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not at a machine where I can confirm it but I suspect that the reason you are seeing this behavior is that your batch running within `System.startTest()` is in its own scope and may not see the values which you inserted earlier in your test method.

Here's an example cobbled together from the code provided above:

```
@isTest
private class BatchTest {

    static testMethod void testBatchDidGoodStuff() {

        // switch context to the test scope
        System.startTest();
    
        //Create Custom Setting
        RoundRobinAssignments__c RoundRobin = new RoundRobinAssignments__c(
            Name = 'Master', OpportunityNonPackageLeads__c = 5, 
            OpportunityPackageLead__c = 10);
        upsert RoundRobin;
    
        Database.executeBatch(new BatchOpportunityOwnerAssignment()); 
    
        System.stopTest(); // cause the batch to execute
    
        // System.assert(your logic); // assert the correct behavior occurred in the batch
    }
}
```